# Automate Calling to mobile number for Authentication

Tags: java, mobile, native, phone-call, two-factor-authentication

I have seen few applications providing voice call for 2FA where the service calls our mobile number and tells a code which we have to type for authentication.

I would like to implement one of those in my JAVA application.

As far as I have searched there are many third party providers for performing this action but I would like to implement my own with JAVA native API and prefer avoiding third party APIs.

Is it possible? Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I looked into JTAPI. It looks like we need a provider(Avaya or Cisco) which acts as a interface between the application and the user. How to contact these providers?

Answer (score 0):

It is as easy as calling a URL.You dont need any API for that. You can try Twilio or Nexmo.
See Nexmo's example below (they also have Java libraries, but this one is 'pure' REST):

```
https://rest.nexmo.com/call/json?api_key=your-key&api_secret=your-secret&to=+99450_destination_number&answer_url=https://myserver/call_callback.php
```

However, relying on classic telephony and SMS is not recommended.

Comment: I have checked Twilio and Nexmo. They are APIs which is what I don't want.

Comment: As far as I know, Java can operate with either Native functions or APIs. If you are looking for a native Java function to make a phone call, I can tell for sure such function does not exist. What is wrong with APIs, btw? If it is a security thing, then it is like putting grids on windows whereas doors are wide open: voice calls are so insecure and easy to intercept that relying on external APIs does not add any more risk at all.

Comment: There is JTAPI but I did not understand it completly.

Comment: Had a quick look at JTAPI, seems like it is a native implementation of SIP client functions. This conceptually does not change anything.  Calls will still need to be done by a server (SIP/VoIP) that you will have to "trust". So instead of sending an HTTP request to Nexmo, you will send a SIP/UDP request to a Voip server. The only scenario where JTAPI is better addressing your concern is to host a SIP device (like Cisco Voip router) yourself on-prem.

Comment: I want to learn how to implement that stuff. So, there is no point using Nexmo or Twilio. From your comment, it looks like I will have to host a VoIP Server and my client will have to communicate with the server to call mobiles. Though I did not understand the terms SIP & VoIP, looks like this is what I was looking for. Any advice on the server side part?

Comment: I would not say that part is something worth spending time learning. But in a nutshell you need a voip router that has access to PSTN either via classic telephony lines (ISDN) or via a SIP provider. Something like Cisco 1921. I can recommend something easier (like astersik or freeswitch) but there will be nothing to learn, chances are that it will just work :)